# Are there Bad teachers? Is Mara in the Sanga?

Tags: ethics, teachers, sangha, sankhara

I have had an experience with a top teacher, Regional Assistant Teacher, and Center Manager acting in ways very disturbing to the path. Later I saw clearly that they were controlled by Mara or had energy in the Mara realm, may be interested in making very difficult Sankhara. How can a serious student navigate these dangers to reach liberation? If the Sangha has lies, killing beings, Traps students and Practitioner s in a the type of life a student of Buddha seeks to be free from? Are these dangers in monks? Can we admit and face what influence we have acting upon us or act out ourselves or will this lead to more ego I am, I am not... Etc. More confusion and controversy.

Comment: Good to think about why one meets such, goes after such, as such is a matter of Upanissaya. [Cunda Sutta](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.1.05.than_en.html). Why does one seek for Dhamma among businnes and trade. Look there disciples quote even without giving reputation.

Answer (score 7):

There have always been bad men robed as monks. If we have clear moral discernment, we will avoid them.

> 307. There are many evil characters and uncontrolled men wearing the saffron robe. These wicked men will be born in states of woe because
>        of their evil deeds.
> 308. It would be better to swallow a red-hot iron ball, blazing like fire, than as an immoral and uncontrolled monk to eat the alms of the
>        people.
>
> Dhammapada

Answer (score 1):

Be committed to the path. The solution lies in the quality of consciousness. Just like Metta Sutta says that Metta drives off anger or angry people, you keep investing time and energy in spiritual advancement and you will have no problems with any kind of negative people.

> "Neither fire, poison, nor weapons can touch one." -- [Metta
>   (Mettanisamsa) Sutta: Good Will](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.016.than.html)

I have been living in ashram in India for two years. There have been many deviations from teachers instructions, cheating, politics and hinderances imposed by neophyte students. The best is to be committed to your path so if someone becomes bad or whole Sanga crashes, you will still be on the path making spiritual advancement.

Comment: And become red...

Comment: What's red? It that an acronym?

Comment: Yes: affection, love, hate, blood, fire, marxism, communism: in short Mara within the sangh(khara).. But usually they would see them burning and promoting it.

Comment: I think that's @SamanaJohann commenting on (reacting to, disliking) the colour of your avatar.

Comment: It's orange iwth a letter "U".

Comment: I think he complained about "red" previously e.g. as a comment to [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/33965/254) and [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/33901/254).

Comment: Doesn't make sense.